# Ajax Post works locally but not on production server

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I ran into an issue where I have an Ajax Post that generates a document serverside. It works great on localhost but when it's published on server side, I receive a 404 in the console.

Here's my code ajax call:

```
$("#btn1330").on("click", function () {
    $("#loading").show();
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/AdminReports/GenerateForm1330",
        data: {
            urd: {
                "URSID": $(".form-1330-input").val() //this is a string value
            }
        }
    }).done(function () {
        $("#loading").hide();
    });
});
```

It is received on controller side (AdminReports) with this:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GenerateForm1330(UnlimitedReleaseDocument urd)
{
 //my code for generating a document and saving to desktop is here
  return Json(true)
 }
```

On localhost, this works as expected with a 200 success, however, when pushed to staging, I see the following error in console:

```
> POST https://urs-staging.jpl.nasa.gov/AdminReports/GenerateForm1330
> 404 (Not Found)
```

Any ideas as to why this doesn't work on staging/production? The URL in the console error is exactly the route that it needs to hit so I'm confused! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Jordan, please take a look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/773638/2026740

Comment: So the `AdminReports` folder of `subdomain.something.nasa.gov` isn't accessible over http, I guess.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette so you think this may be a security issue?

Comment: The requested page has to be available over HTTP for sure, And your does not like to be. So I guess that's the issue. Now the reason may vary. I can't tell.